# Razor view- C# - Disable read only textbox's

Tags: c#, razor

I tried several answers posted on stackoverflow. However, the following doesn't seem to work:

```
@Html.TextArea("Comments", Model.Comments, Model.ReadOnly ? new { @disabled = "disabled"} : null)
```

I also tried:

```
@Html.TextArea("Comments", Model.Comments, Model.ReadOnly ? new { disabled = "disabled"} : null)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read my question? I already tried that

Comment: You did not specify what answers you already looked at, there's no way I could know whether you saw that before or not.

Comment: Sorry, thats my mistake. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Voting to close due to the desired behavior being unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a custom variable to set it. I don't think the conditional is acceptable in the arguments of the HtmlHelper.

```
@{
    var htmlAttributes = Model.ReadOnly ? new { disabled = "disabled" } : null;
}

@Html.TextArea("Comments", Model.Comments, htmlAttributes)
```

Comment: I am going to try that! Any idea if I can add similar parameters to BOTH the true and false conditions? Without mentioning that in both

Comment: As long as the result is a valid collection of attributes you should be able to construct it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that MVC likes a `null` here. What you need as a third parameter (which expects `object`) is a default empty anonymous instance instead of `null`:

```
Model.ReadOnly ? (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : (object)new { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your ternary operation in parentheses

```
@Html.TextArea("Comments", Model.Comments, (Model.ReadOnly ? new { @disabled = "disabled"} : null) )
```